# How use key links on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS. My issue is like this. After submitting your form it is sending an email with a link to your artwork. It look like this

`domain.com/?key=1y2p6pzc2lxj33w5b996cd4ufq`.

When I click the link is going to the website homepage instead to your artwork. And the link look like this:

`domain.comk/?key=1y2p6pzc2lxj33w5b996cd4ufq/#home`
 in the address bar, which is equal with `domain.com/#home`. I don't know if I explained properly.

```
var neonApp = angular.module('neonApp', ['ngRoute', 'PatternForm']);


//caching
neonApp.run(['$rootScope', '$templateCache', '$location', '$window', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $templateCache, $location, $window, $timeout) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      //$templateCache.removeAll();
   });

   $rootScope
       .$on('$routeChangeSuccess',

               function (event) {

                   if (!$window.ga) {
                       return;
                   }
                   $timeout(function () {

                       $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: $location.path() });
                   }, 100);

               });
}]);


//Routing
neonApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
        controller  : 'homeController'
    })
    .when('/drawing', {
        templateUrl : 'views/drawing.html',
        controller  : 'drawController'
    })
    .when('/choose', {
        templateUrl : 'views/choose.html',
        controller  : 'chooseController'
    })
    .when('/submit', {
        templateUrl : 'views/submit.html',
        controller  : 'submitController'
    })
    .when('/gallery', {
        templateUrl : 'views/gallery.html',
        controller  : 'galleryController'
    })
    .when('/support_error', {
        templateUrl : 'views/support_error.html',
        controller  : 'supportErrorController'
    })
    .when('/success', {
        templateUrl : 'views/success.html',
        controller  : 'successController'
    })
    .when('/error', {
        templateUrl: 'views/form_error.html',
        controller: 'errorController'
    })

    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});

});
```

Comment: Will try domain.com?key=1y2p6pzc2lxj33w5b996cd4ufq instead of domain.com/?key=1y2p6pzc2lxj33w5b996cd4ufq

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: Shouldn't your link be like `domain.comk/#home?key=1y2p6pzc2lxj33w5b996cd4ufq` ? How is this key used in your app?